# how to add a reaction to a post (social website)

Tags: sql, theory

I'm rather new to sql and i was wondering what would be the best way to add reactions to posts as we can see for exemple in twitter where you answer a tweet, so far i've worked out these 2 ways but i don't know which one should be done:

- add a reaction table which will have for pk **id_react** and **id_post**, with id_react in auto_increment with each reaction made by any user on any page of the site

*this one is easier to put in place but i don't know if it's really viable for big scale web sites as it would result in a really big ass table and i was asking myself if it wouldn't make the search of those reactions slow in the long run*

- create a new table reaction for every post that is created

*this one would "erase" the problem of the DB size although it would mean to moderate as many reaction tables as there is of **id_post**; so here I am not knowing which solution would be theoretically the best for this kind of problem*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new table per post does not look great to me. You may end up with millions of tables, most of them empty, for no performance benefit, and a lot of maintenance burden.

I would go with just one more table that stores all the reactions, and has `post_id` as a foreign key.

But your intuition about having more separate tables is not wrong: a similar feature is known as [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)), and is available in all major relational databases.